# Could not find method storeFile() for arguments [C:/Users/tienn/key.jks] on SigningConfig_Decorated

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I built release app bundle with this error, I don't know where I am wrong.

```
Could not find method storeFile() for arguments [C:/Users/tienn/key.jks] on SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=key, keyPassword=***, storeType=jks, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.
```

This is my app_dir/android/app/build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile']
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

This is my app_dir/android/key.properties

```
storePassword=***
keyPassword=***
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:/Users/tienn/key.jks
```

Many thanks!

Comment: C:\Users\... is a path on your Windows machine. And you are with your Android device in town.

Comment: Thank @blackapps for your comment but it not solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function takes a file as an argument, so you should use this instead

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) //<-----file here
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```